# Как скрыть дочерние категории?

Tags: jquery

Как сделать скрытие вложений в дереве категорий ? На главную категорию нажимаю и что бы дочерние скрылись. или подскажите какие события почитать JQuery что бы разобраться.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Контейнер `.cat`, название категории (оно же кнопка) `.cat_label`, контент категории `.cat_sub` - при нажатии на название категории открывается контент, в который можно вложить ту же конструкцию (работает в обе стороны, можно по дефолту задать `display: block;` при нажатии `display: none;`)

```js
const catLabel = $('.cat').children('.cat_label');

catLabel.on('click', toggleSubCat);

function toggleSubCat() {
  $(this).siblings('.cat_sub').toggleClass('show');
}
```

```css
.cat_sub {
  display: none;
}

.cat_sub.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="cat">
  <button class="cat_label">Category #1</button>
  <div class="cat_sub">
    <div class="cat">
      <button class="cat_label">Category #1 sub</button>
      <div class="cat_sub">
        <div class="cat">
          <button class="cat_label">Category #1 zag zag</button>
          <div class="cat_sub">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cat">
          <button class="cat_label">Category #1 zag zag</button>
          <div class="cat_sub">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cat">
          <button class="cat_label">Category #1 zag zag</button>
          <div class="cat_sub">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cat">
      <button class="cat_label">Category #2 sub</button>
      <div class="cat_sub">
        <div class="cat">
          <button class="cat_label">Category #2 zag zag</button>
          <div class="cat_sub">
            <div class="cat">
              <button class="cat_label">Category #2 zag zag zag</button>
              <div class="cat_sub">
                <div class="cat">
                  <button class="cat_label">Category #2 zag zag zag zag</button>
                  <div class="cat_sub">

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cat">
              <button class="cat_label">Category #2 zag zag zag</button>
              <div class="cat_sub">

              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="cat">
              <button class="cat_label">Category #2 zag zag zag</button>
              <div class="cat_sub">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно. но нельзя было попроще код написать ) мой уровень JQuery это скрыть и раскрыть какой то элемент.

Comment: 7 строчек, куда уж проще ... xDD

Comment: У меня в форыче код не работает ((

Comment: добавить код в который интегрируешь это. Не знаю, что значит "в форыче не работает"

Comment: Добавляю в цикле вот это и не работает, а вне все ок `<div class="cat">
    <button class="cat_label">Category #1</button>
    <div class="cat_sub">
        4545
    </div>
</div>`

Comment: В каком цикле то? Создай наверное новую задачу, либо к своей пример кода и разметки добавь, сложно понять в какой цикл это ты пытаешься всунуть, этот скрипт работает для всех уже существующих на странице элементов с нужной структурой, если динамически строишь категории, то после построения всех надо этот код запускать, а не на каждую итерацию. В общем я бы советовал как-то код показать, иначе сложно понять что не так.

Comment: У меня выводит дерево рекурсией и внутри нее код твой не работает. Я уже по разному пытался

Comment: создай лучше отдельный вопрос с примером кода, я так точно не разберусь как ты и что делаешь.